# Select rows of a certain level of a category conditioned to that there is a previous row of another level of the same category in less than 180s

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe `df` that summarizes activity or depth for several fish individuals (`ID`) over time (`DateTime`). Here an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,3),
                DateTime=c("2017-05-08 10:15:23","2017-05-08 10:19:31","2017-05-08 10:11:12","2017-05-08 10:02:23","2017-05-08 10:21:32","2017-05-08 10:15:52","2017-05-08 10:13:23","2017-05-08 10:22:19","2017-05-08 10:19:42","2017-05-08 10:21:27","2017-05-08 10:16:07","2017-05-08 10:24:53","2017-05-08 10:28:39","2017-05-08 10:23:48","2017-05-08 10:33:01"),
                DataType=c("Activity","Depth","Depth","Activity","Activity","Activity","Depth","Depth","Activity","Depth","Activity","Depth","Depth","Activity","Activity"),
                Value=c(0.89,24,19,1.8,1.1,0.7,17,28,2.1,20,1.35,12,19,0.4,0.97))

df1

   ID            DateTime DataType Value
1   1 2017-05-08 10:15:23 Activity  0.89
2   1 2017-05-08 10:19:31    Depth 24.00
3   2 2017-05-08 10:11:12    Depth 19.00
4   3 2017-05-08 10:02:23 Activity  1.80
5   1 2017-05-08 10:21:32 Activity  1.10
6   2 2017-05-08 10:15:52 Activity  0.70
7   3 2017-05-08 10:13:23    Depth 17.00
8   1 2017-05-08 10:22:19    Depth 28.00
9   2 2017-05-08 10:19:42 Activity  2.10
10  2 2017-05-08 10:21:27    Depth 20.00
11  3 2017-05-08 10:16:07 Activity  1.35
12  1 2017-05-08 10:24:53    Depth 12.00
13  3 2017-05-08 10:28:39    Depth 19.00
14  2 2017-05-08 10:23:48 Activity  0.40
15  3 2017-05-08 10:33:01 Activity  0.97
```

For methodological reasons, I need to select activity values that match one condition: there is a previous depth data in less than 3 minutes for the same individual. That is, I need activity data for which I have previous depth data in less than 3 minutes. I would need the resulting dataframe to have those activity values that meet this condition as well as the previous depth values.

I would expect something like this:

```
> df2

  ID            DateTime DataType Value
1  1 2017-05-08 10:19:31    Depth 24.00
2  1 2017-05-08 10:21:32 Activity  1.10 # Activity value in less than 3 minutes with regard a depth data
3  2 2017-05-08 10:21:27    Depth 20.00
4  2 2017-05-08 10:23:48 Activity  0.40 # Activity value in less than 3 minutes with regard a depth data
5  3 2017-05-08 10:13:23    Depth 17.00
6  3 2017-05-08 10:16:07 Activity  1.35 # Activity value in less than 3 minutes with regard a depth data
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first convert `DateTime` to `POSIXct` type, create a new column which has latest `"Depth"` time, subtract the `"Depth"` time with current `DateTime` for each group (`ID`) and select rows where `DataType == 'Activity'` and the time difference is less than 180 seconds.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime), 
         diffTime = replace(DateTime, DataType != "Depth", NA)) %>%
  arrange(ID, DateTime) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  tidyr::fill(diffTime) %>%
  mutate(diffTime = difftime(DateTime, diffTime, units = "secs")) %>%
  slice({i1 <- which(DataType == 'Activity' & diffTime < 180);c(i1-1, i1)}) %>%
  select(-diffTime)


#     ID DateTime            DataType Value
#  <dbl> <dttm>              <fct>    <dbl>
#1     1 2017-05-08 10:19:31 Depth    24   
#2     1 2017-05-08 10:21:32 Activity  1.1 
#3     2 2017-05-08 10:21:27 Depth    20   
#4     2 2017-05-08 10:23:48 Activity  0.4 
#5     3 2017-05-08 10:13:23 Depth    17   
#6     3 2017-05-08 10:16:07 Activity  1.35
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using a non-equi join in `data.table` 
 and for each row of Depth with a match, rbind the Depth row with an Activity row that is within 3mins:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- names(df1)
setDT(df1)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")][,
    c("start", "end") := .(DateTime, DateTime + 3*60)]

ans <- df1[DataType=="Activity"][df1[DataType=="Depth"],
    on=.(ID, start>=start, start<=end), nomatch=0L,
    by=.EACHI, rbindlist(use.names=FALSE,
        list(mget(paste0("i.", cols)), mget(cols)))
][, (1:3) := NULL]   #remove unwanted columns

#set column names as desired
setnames(ans, gsub("i.","", names(ans), fixed=TRUE))[]
```

output:

```
   ID            DateTime DataType Value
1:  1 2017-05-08 10:19:31    Depth 24.00
2:  1 2017-05-08 10:21:32 Activity  1.10
3:  3 2017-05-08 10:13:23    Depth 17.00
4:  3 2017-05-08 10:16:07 Activity  1.35
5:  2 2017-05-08 10:21:27    Depth 20.00
6:  2 2017-05-08 10:23:48 Activity  0.40
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12. One doubth: in my real data I have names instead of numbers for the `ID`. What should I do in your code? If for instance, I have the individuals `David`, `Anna`, `Sophie` and `Marco`, what should I change in your code?

Comment: you should not have to change anything for ID. it will just be a key used in the join